# Why British English speakers repeat something said to them?

Tags: phrases

Here in the UK When talking to Britons I see this pattern e.g.

Me: We are going to the zoo next week.
Him: Are we?

Or

Me: We had a lovely dinner last night while Susan joined us at the last minute.
Other people: Did she now? How come she is in London?

does it make you sound like the listener is paying attention or is it a style or is it mandantory in English culture?

Comment: It isn't 'mandatory', it's just one way of showing that the other person is taking a friendly interest in what you have said.

Comment: For negative statements the listener can say 'Don't you? Didn't he?" etc. Some regional variations. If I say "I didn't see any cats today", my Lancashire wife will say "Did you not?". It's a friendly/polite thing, where saying nothing or just "Uh-huh" would be seen as unfriendly or rude.

Comment: There's probably more than one thing happening here. In "Me: We are going to the zoo next week. Him: Are we?" it sounds like the second speaker is politely disagreeing, although they may just be saying that they were unaware of that arrangement until now. While "Did she now?" is an expression of surprise but not necessarily disagreement or disbelief.

Comment: And "Did she hell!" (or some other profanity) is an expression of strong disagreement.